# Maximum frequency of any mobile phone speaker

Tags: sound

Which is the maximum frequency of a speaker of any common mobile phone? I would like to use sound to repel some animals, so I need playback sampling rate to be above 44100 Hz.

Comment: If you want to have your mobile phone _emit_ a sound at frequencies above the range of human hearing in order to repel animals, you might want to first consider the limitations of the loudspeaker built into the phone.

Comment: This is a product specification question (ask the manufacturers), not a DSP question.

Comment: It's more likely that the DAC applies filters which force output within the audible spectrum. Your speaker might very well have the ability to produce frequencies higher than this, it's just likely that the audio hardware connected to it will filter this out by default.

Comment: Which sounds repel which animals, exactly?  Is this effect based in reality or [are you just assuming that products which claim this effect actually work](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5021/155)?

Comment: minimum 20 Hz......And Maximum 20000....
So Minimum use A Hear phone. ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The native sampling frequency of iOS devices is 44100 Hz, while Android devices can operate at either 8, 16, 24, 44.1 or 48 kHz. Support of all of these depends on Android device manufacturer, however most Android support all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum limit is probably like $20$ kHz because that’s the human top limit and there is no point in having a higher frequency speakers unless you want to use it as an animal repeller so in that case some manufacturers may chose to add a second special piezoelectric speaker (metal diaphragm) for ultrasounds.

Don’t confuse the speaker frequency with the audio device sampling rate. The sampling rate is how often the samples of the original natural sound was recorded or if there was an artificial sound something like how often there is a change in the frequency. This gives the clarity of the sound but also a $44$ kHz sampling rate can reproduce a maximum $44/2= 22$ kHz to be outputted to the speaker.